# Store Terminal Output in a File ros melodic cpp

Tags: ros, pcl

I have a pcd file with x y z coordinates from point cloud.

Now I have another cpp file from where I print x y z coordinates on terminal. ( This is just the coordinates not a point cloud)
I want to store this in another file in order to compare it with pcd file.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to store it directly from stdout? There are a couple of different ways to go about this that are probably easier.

You can simply publish the `(x,y,z)` data and record it with [rosbag record](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record) and then export via [rosbag_to_csv](https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/rosbag_to_csv).

You could also just write the values to a file directly in the code instead of printing it out. Since you did not specify Python or C++ here is a quick example in Python

```
f = open('your_output_file.csv', 'a')
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    #Whatever ops to get data
    x,y,z = get_the_data()
    output_str = str(x)+','+str(y)+','+str(z)
    f.write(output_str)
```

ROS will also automatically log output from `rospy.log*()` functions. You can control where this is stored by exporting the environmental variable `ROS_LOG_DIR`. Note that this may not work 100% correctly for `print()` statements

Finally, if you really really need to use stdout for some reason you can always redirect the output from however you're launching the node. Ex: `roslaunch your_package your_launch.launch >> some_file.txt`

Comment: Thank you. The quick response helped.

I used the second option.

The name of the file is foo.csv
But I cannot seem to find the location of where it is stored.

Comment: std::ofstream myFile("foo.csv");
        myFile << "x";
        myFile << "y\n";
            {

            double distance = sqrt(pow(point_x - x, 2.0) + pow(point_y - y, 2.0));
                      
            if (distance < rad) {
                std::cout<<"xcoord "<<x<<" y coord "<<y<<std::endl;                
                myFile << x;
                myFile << y<<"\n";
            }}           
        myFile.close();

Comment: @Sant you’re using a relative path for that file name so it will be in whatever folder the program is run out of. If you’re using a local workspace it would be something like `workspace/devel/lib/package_name`. It’s probably better and easier to give it an absolute path such as `/home/your_user/foo.csv`